# Java Android How To Save Multiple CheckBox To String If Checked and Store To SharedPref and Retrieve It As A String

Tags: java, android, checkbox, android-sharedpreferences

So I have 2 screen one to store the other to retrieve. What I want ultimately is storing the checked checkbox into sharedPref, retrieve it as a STRING and put it inside an ArrayList to shuffle for a random STRING that was SELECTED.

So far I tried many solutions but none worked. I always get the unchecked checkbox as well. I only want checked even if I just select ONE of the checkbox. Any advise would be appreciated.

EDIT: I have solve the problem...at least for now. Look at the UpdateReceive.java to see the solution. But however for other screens I will have 9 Checkboxes and the possibilities are too tedious to do it this way. So are there any better methods out there?

**Storing.java**

```
SharedPreferences sharedMode = getSharedPreferences("MySharedMode", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
final SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedMode.edit();
editor.clear();
editor.commit();

        if ( cbCool.isChecked() || cbHeat.isChecked()) {
            editor.putBoolean("Cool", cbCool.isChecked());
            editor.putBoolean("Heat", cbHeat.isChecked());
            editor.commit();
}
```

**Receieve.java**

```
SharedPreferences sharedMode = getSharedPreferences("MySharedMode", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
String heat = String.valueOf(sharedMode.getBoolean("Heat", false));
String cool = String.valueOf(sharedMode.getBoolean("Cool", false));

if (heat != null && cool != null) {
    String m_heat = "Heat";
    String m_cool = "Cool";
    List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
    list.add(m_heat);
    list.add(m_cool);
    Collections.shuffle(list);
    String randMode = list.get(0);
    tvMode.setText(randMode);
}
```

**UpdatedReceive.java**

```
if (heat == "true" && cool != "true") {
        tvMode.setText("Heat");
    }
    else if (heat != "true" && cool == "true") {
        tvMode.setText("Cool");
    }
    else if (heat =="true" && cool == "true") {
        String m_heat = "Heat";
        String m_cool = "Cool";
        List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
        list.add(m_heat);
        list.add(m_cool);
        Collections.shuffle(list);
        String randMode = list.get(0);
        tvMode.setText(randMode);
    }
```

Comment: Good question formatting (+1) welcome to stackoverflow buddy.